# How to fix the warning, "TSC frequency mismatch between VM (2808009 kHz) and host (2807995 kHz), and TSC scaling unavailble" on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run virtual device on Android studio AVM, I get this warning and internet is not working on the device.

Comment: What is your setup?

Comment: @Patrick What do you mean by setup....

Comment: I mean your computer hardware/software settings etc.

Comment: OS:- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Hardware:- processor: Intel® Core™ i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz, memory: 15.3 GiB @Patrick this is my computer configuration